# save spark ML model in azure blobs

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I tried saving my machine learning model in pyspark to azure blob. But this is giving error.

```
lr.save('wasbs:///user/remoteuser/models/')

Illegal Argument Exception: Cannot initialize WASB file system, URI authority not recognized.'
```

Also tried,

```
m = lr.save('wasbs://'+container_name+'@'+storage_account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/models/')
```

But getting unable to identify user identity in stack trace.
P.S. : I am not using Azure HDInsight. I am just using Databricks and Azure blob storage

Answer (score 0):

To access Azure Blob Storage from Azure Databricks directly (not mounted), you have to set an an account access key:

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
```

or a SAS for a container. Then you should be able to access the Blob Storage:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
```

Comment: Actually reading is possible. But how do i save spark ml models in azure blob. As a work around, i created a text file with model layers and model weights and then using azure-blob-storage library using block_blob_service. But a spark query would directly smoothen the workflow